# Why is $xy^{-1}$ equal to 1?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, integers

$x^3≡y^3 \mod5 \iff (xy^{−1})^3≡1 \mod 5$ all I have to do now is to prove that $xy^{-1}$ is equal to $1$.

Can someone tell me how that can be done?

Comment: Note that $0^3=0,1^3=1,2^3=3,3^3=2,4^3=4\bmod5$.. All different. So if $x^3=y^3\bmod5$ then $x=y\bmod5$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ and $y$ are divided by $5$ it's wrong.

If no, it's true because $$(xy^{-1})^3\equiv x^3y^{-3}\equiv y^3y^{-3}=1$$

Now, prove that $$a^3\equiv1\Leftrightarrow a\equiv1,$$ for which use $$a^4\equiv1$$ by the Fermat's little theorem.

I'll prove the Fermat's little theorem for $p=29$.

Let $\gcd(a,29)=1$ and $ia\equiv r_i,$ where $1\leq r_i\leq28.$

Thus, $$\prod_{i=1}^{28}(ia)\equiv\prod_{i=1}^{28}r_i$$ or
$$a^{28}28!\equiv28!$$ or
$$a^{28}\equiv1.$$
I used that for any integers $\{i,j\}\subset[1,28]$ we have:
$$ia\equiv ja\Leftrightarrow (i-j)a\equiv0\Leftrightarrow i=j.$$
Now, if $a^3\equiv1,$ so $a^{27}\equiv1$ or $a^{28}\equiv a,$ which gives $a\equiv1.$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103865/discussion-on-answer-by-michael-rozenberg-why-is-xy-1-equal-to-1).

Answer (score 0):

$x^3\equiv y^3\implies (x^3)^3\equiv(y^3)^3\iff x^9\equiv y^9 $.

Now apply *lil' Fermat*.

Comment: Thank you. But what IF it was modulo 39? We could say a^38≡1 but how can I prove that a^3≡1⇔a≡1?

Comment: You can't say so as $\varphi(39)=24$. Furthermore, in this case, $3$ is *not* coprime to the modulus.

Comment: And what about 29 then?

Comment: It is prime and $3$ was coprime to $29$, so one could find a multiple of $3$ which is exactly $1$ more than a multiple of $\varphi(29)$. For $39$ this is impossible, as $\varphi(39)$ *is* a multiple of $3$.

Comment: I like the idea of a Fermat comic featuring adult Fermat and his sidekick L'il Fermat, getting into hilarious scrapes.  Often the day is saved by L'il Fermat's timely deployment of his famous theorem. And a running joke is that Big Fermat keeps trying to deploy _his_ famous theorem, but is never able to do it successfully! (Often, because it won't work in a confined space. “Drat, if only this storeroom were a little larger! It would be truly marvelous, I assure you.”)